# Django: can POST happen by accident?

Tags: django, post, get, view

In Django, I check for login status and permissions for pages that require logins. However, right now I'm only checking them in the case of a `get` inside views, since it is possible to try and access a page that you're not allowed to access.

For example, say I have a section for logged-in users only, like `/user_account/`. If someone types in the URL manually I'd of course have to check if he's logged in or not. I would perform this check inside the `get` section.

But say if on `user_account` there's also a form, which would fall into the `post` section of the view. Would I still need to check if the user is logged in?

That is, is it possible to somehow accidentally POST to that page when I'm preventing you from `get`-ting it in the first place?

Hope this question is clear.

Comment: *Always* check if a check is needed for access control. It could be accidentally done by clearing cookies and it could be purposefully done by a curios person.

Comment: Could you show how does you view currently look? Particularly the parts that check if a user is logged in and the part that does GET and POST request processing. Thanks.

Comment: If a page requires authentication I recommend using @login_required decorator this will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure - write a test and see if it fails:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class LoginPostTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_unauthorized_post(self):
        data = {}  # TODO: fill the data
        response = self.client.post('/user_account/', data)
        # TODO: assert you've been redirected to the login url

    def test_authorized_post(self):
        self.client.login(username='<username>', password='<password>')

        data = {}  # TODO: fill the data
        response = self.client.post('/user_account/', data)
        # TODO: assert not being redirected
```